# How to determine which device Ask To Buy appears on?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, parental-controls

I use parental controls and Ask to Buy on child devices so we can approve purchases. This generally works great.  I have my primary iOS device, an iPhone, then a couple secondary devices - an iPad and another older iPhone without a sim card.

Recently Ask to Buy prompts are not appearing on my primary device and instead only appear on the secondary iPhone. Sometimes this is a problem because that secondary device isn't always plugged in and has little to no power left.  And I've had issues in the past where purchase prompts will appear on one device but not all, and without any obvious reason which one is chosen.

All of my devices are logged in, with my same account. None appear to have any issues showing in account settings on the device.  Ideally, my preference would be that Ask to Buy prompts appear on all of my logged in devices at the same time, and I could approve no matter which device I was using that the time.  Beyond that, if it only has to be one device, I would prefer it by my "primary" device that is my daily driver phone, although I'm not aware of a way to mark a device as such.

Is there a way to control which parental device 'Ask to Buy' prompts on or a way to get it to prompt on all parent account devices?

Comment: I have the same nightmare regarding 'ask to buy'.  Could be on any one of my devices (or my wife's, since either of us can approve).  Very inconsistent behavior, from what I've experienced.